# How to convert multiple tables in one page into UL lists with JS / jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I would like to convert multiple tables on one page into UL lists.

For each table I have created a numbered class, so as not to find the contents of one table inside another.

This is because **JS duplicates me the contents** of the variables.

What I would like to achieve is to convert all the tables in UL list, referring to them with a common class, without having to create a numbering.

So I can create multiple tables, without having the counter limit to have to increment each time, if I want to use multiple tables on the same page.

Thanks in advance!

This is what I tried to do:

```js
(function() {

  /*Counter by class numbering so as not to have duplicate table content in others.
   This is the limiting factor: I can create 3 tables, if I want more, I have to increase it every time*/

  var tableInPage = 3;

  for (let i = 0; i <= tableInPage; i++) {

    var ul = $('<ul>');

    $('.table-list-' + tableInPage[i] + ' ' + 'table tr').each(function() {
      var li = $('<li>')
      $('th, td', this).each(function() {
        var span = $('<span>').html(this.innerHTML);
        i.append(span);
      });
      ul.append(li);
    })

    $('.table-list-' + tableInPage[i] + ' ' + 'table').replaceWith(ul);
  }


})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Table 1-->
<div class='table-list-1'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Table 2-->
<div class='table-list-2'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: "*JS duplicates me the contents*" - js just does what you tell it to do...

Comment: You have a couple of typos - `i.append` -> `li.append` and `tableInPage[i]` should be just `i`  [edit: fix ironic typo in typos]

Comment: You *could* just do `var tableInPage = $("div[class^='table-list']).length;` - but better to skip the `tableInPage` and `table-list-n` completely

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. [JSFiddle Working Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2j8qvsf7/)

**HTML**

```
 <!-- Table 1-->
 <div class='table-list'>
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>A</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
 </div>

<!-- Table 2-->
<div class='table-list'>
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>A</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 <!-- Table 3-->
 <div class='table-list'>
    <table>
      <tr>
          <td>A</td>
          <td>A</td>
      </tr>
     </table>
 </div>
 
 and so on .....
```

**JS/JQ**

```
(function () {

/*you don't have to give numbering class to each table. Just give all of them same class and the code will do the rest*/

   $(".table-list").each(function(){
   
    var ul = $('<ul>');
                  
        $('table tr', this).each(function () {
        
            $('th, td', this).each(function () {
              var li = $('<li>')
              var span = $('<span>').html(this.innerHTML);
              li.append(span);
              ul.append(li);
           });
 
         });
         
         $('table', this).replaceWith(ul);
   })

  })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I've rewritten your code a bit, so now you should not have to change any `jQuery` if you add another table.

```
(function() {

  $('div[class^="table-list"]').each(function() {

    var ul = $('<ul>');

    $('table tr',this).each(function() {
      var li = $('<li>')
      $('th, td', this).each(function() {
        var span = $('<span>').html(this.innerHTML);
        li.append(span);
      });
      ul.append(li);
    })

    $('table tr',this).replaceWith(ul);
  })
})();
```

**Demo**

```js
(function() {

  $('div[class^="table-list"]').each(function() {

    var ul = $('<ul>');

    $('table tr',this).each(function() {
      var li = $('<li>')
      $('th, td', this).each(function() {
        var span = $('<span>').html(this.innerHTML);
        li.append(span);
      });
      ul.append(li);
    })

    $('table tr',this).replaceWith(ul);
  })
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Table 1-->
<div class='table-list-1'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Table 2-->
<div class='table-list-2'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just walk this inside out for each element and replace simply with the contained HTML.

```js
(function() {
  $('div[class^=table-list-]').each(function() {
    $(this).find('th, td').each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith($('<span>').html(this.innerHTML));
    });
    $(this).find('tr').each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith($('<li>').html(this.innerHTML))
    });
    $(this).find('tbody').each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith($('<ul>').html(this.innerHTML));
    });
    $(this).find('table').each(function() {
      $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
    });
    // unclear the requirement to replace the div with the ul but this does that
    $(this).replaceWith(this.innerHTML);
  });

})();
```

```css
ul {

  border: solid red 1px;
}
li {

  border: solid lime 1px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Table 1-->
<div class='table-list-1'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Table 2-->
<div class='table-list-2'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there. Your code just needs a little touch up and it would work. Please change:

```
//i.append(span) to:
li.append(span)

//and tableInPage[i] to:
(i+1)
```

**DEMO**

```js
(function() {

  /*Counter by class numbering so as not to have duplicate table content in others.
   This is the limiting factor: I can create 3 tables, if I want more, I have to increase it every time*/

  var tableInPage = 3;

  for (let i = 0; i <= tableInPage; i++) {

    var ul = $('<ul>');

    $('.table-list-' + (i+1) + ' ' + 'table tr').each(function() {
      var li = $('<li>')
      $('th, td', this).each(function() {
        var span = $('<span>').html(this.innerHTML);
        li.append(span);
      });
      ul.append(li);
    })

    $('.table-list-' + (i+1) + ' ' + 'table').replaceWith(ul);
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Table 1-->
<div class='table-list-1'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Table 2-->
<div class='table-list-2'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>A</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```